# What is meant by: "When an activity calls startActivity(Intent), this call is sent to the OS."? (full context in description)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Below is the context of the quote from an Android programming book.

> The simplest way one activity can start
>   another is with the startActivity
>   method:
>   public void startActivity(Intent intent)
>
> You might guess that
>   startActivity(Intent) is a
>   static method that you call on the
>   Activity subclass that you want to
>   start. But it is not. **When an activity calls
>   startActivity(Intent), this
>   call is sent to the OS.
>   In particular, it is sent to a part of the OS
>   called the ActivityManager.** The
>   ActivityManager then creates the
>   Activity instance and calls its
>   onCreate(Bundle) method. **How does the ActivityManager
>   know which Activity to start? That
>   information is in the Intent parameter.**

I am confused about the bolded parts. What does it mean for a "call to be sent to the OS"? 
My current interpretation is that the ActivityManager is an object, and when the startActivity method is called, one of ActivityManager's instance variables is set to be the intent that startActivity is called with.

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: The wording of the quoted text is rather poor. What is the source? I don't see a question in your question really.

Comment: @marekful the source is the 4th edition of Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide. Is my interpretation of the quoted text correct?